# Magento 2 : Added field for video, music ( mp4 , mp3) upload in admin form

Tags: magento2, adminform, image-upload, file-upload

I try to upload image, video or music player, for that I use **$uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['mp4', 'mp3', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png' ]);** 
, but it doesn't work. Anyone have idea about this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded the media files with ftp to `/pub/media/` and embedded them with the html audio or video tag on the product page.

Here is the code you have to use in the editor on the product page in html mode for the audio file you uploaded before to `/pub/media/` named `example.mp3`:

```
<audio src="https://your-store-domain.tld/pub/media/example.mp3" preload="none" controls="controls"></audio>
```

mp3 can be handled by all major browsers bedside opera mini at the moment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=mp3